# How to refresh ionic 4 app after modifying html?

Tags: ionic4

Sometimes the app refreshes with the new content but sometimes just need to modify some little bug on my html code and it doesnt refreshes, what should I do to make it refreshes with all the changes im doing?

Thank you so much

Comment: which platform are you using (web, android or ios)?

Comment: is cross-platform, not using any emulator, just chrome. But the problem is on runtime it doesnt recompile after little change on html, i have to cancel and turn to do "ionic s"

Comment: You most likely need to clear your browser cache, because nodeJs supposed to take care of refreshing the content except if there is a problem with the build.